# Linking JavaScript Popup to Remote Site

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a script that uses JavaScript to open a popup window featuring links to various countries (e.g. /World/Japan, /World/Venezuela). When you click a link, the main page (the page where you clicked a link to get the popup) forwards to that URL, and the popup stays open (so you can click another link, if you want).

Anyway, I have several websites that feature a World section, with URL's like MySite/World/Japan

So I can copy all my popups folder (including a head section, style sheet, etc.) to each site. But it would be much easier to develop and maintain this stuff, if I could just put it on one website and link the popup links from MySite2, MySite3, etc. to one central popup script(s).

In fact, I'm doing that right now. The problem is that if you're on MySite2, and you click a link that summons a popup file from MySite1, then you click Japan, it takes you to MySite1/World/Japan, not MySite2/World/Japan.

So I'd like to know if there's a way to somehow tell the popup which site it was summoned from - which site should be controlling it.

I should mention that all my sites have ID's. For example, $MySiteID = 'MySite1' or $MySiteID = 'MySite2'

So, if I could click a popup link on MySite2 which opens a popup file on MySite1, I'd like that popup to know that it's SiteID is MySite2, not MySite1.

I hope I explained that clearly. Also, if there's a better way of doing this than JavaScript, I'm all ears. I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: If all the popups are on mysite1 then you could use an url like `http://www.mysite1/world/country` right?

Comment: No, because each URL has different content. For example, MySite1/World/Japan might focus on Japan's geography, while MySite2/World/Japan might focus on Japanese wildlife.

Comment: So you won't link from mysite2 to mystite1? Each site has the same folder and filename structure but different content?

Comment: Yes, each site has a World section, with links like MySite/World/Japan

But each section and page is unique. MySite1/World/Japan and MySite2/World/Japan have different content.

Therefore, I can use a single, central popup to navigate to these links (/World/Japan). I just have to let that popup know which SITE to include in the URL - MySite1/World/Japan vs MySite2/World/Japan

Comment: I think I worked my question incorrectly. I should have simply asked "How can I pass an echo value via a link?"

If I'm surfing MySite2, where $MySiteID = 'MySite2', and I click a link that opens MySite1/Popups/Europe.php, then I'd like Europe.php to open up knowing that it was summoned by MySite2. If I can just make it think that $MySiteID = 'MySite2' (even though it's physically located on MySite1), then I should be able to take it from there. Thanks!